# Allow developers to ask question from companies regarding job listing

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

I am not sure if this is already implemented or not, but at least I have not been able to find this feature.
I am suggesting to include a feature where the candidate can ask questions to the company. The questions can be public or private.

It may also be useful to let the company know bugs about their job posting. 
For example, [this job](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/122486/join-deutsche-bank-technology-team-as-a-lead-deutsche-bank-group) redirects to the company's career home page on applying(Not the specific job page) and when clicking on the particular job position, a blank page opens. It clearly is a bug in the company's website, but still it'd be helpful for the candidate and the company to have it reported too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a option called **Flag a problem with a textbox to describe the problem.** I think this will help you to report your problem or suggestion.

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is the correct course of action; our support team will get in contact with the employer.